App.xaml vs app.xaml and File Name Conventions
WinUI C#, I noticed that the application runs even if the file name for App.xaml is written in lowercase as app.xaml. Are there any technical reasons in C# or WinUI 3 that recommend using an uppercase “A” for App.xaml?
Additionally, for other files and classes, is it technically beneficial? What are the implications of deviating from this convention, such as using snake_case for file names instead?

The benefit is consistency. My expectation is that a class MyClass is inside a file MyClass.cs. In turn, what's the benefit of using snake_case for your file names?

I was worried that there might be some technical limitation, but it seems that's not the case. I simply like snake_case. I'd like to think that there's nothing wrong with using snake_case as long as the naming convention is consistent. Thank you.

Here's what I confirmed about App.xaml and App.xaml.cs:
WORKS (COMPILES)

App.xaml, App.xaml.cs (This is the default.)
App.xaml, app.xaml.cs
app.xaml, App.xaml.cs
app.xaml, app.xaml.cs

DOES NOT WORK (COMPILE)

Any change other than the case.

Ap.xaml, Ap.xaml.cs
App2.xaml, App2.xaml.cs



Since you get the following error message, it seems that the file name is expected to be App.xaml and App.xaml.cs.
CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
For pages or user controls, it seems to be working even if the file name doesn't match.
But as it's mentioned in the comments, I wouldn't do that and keep things consistent.

All I want to do is rename App.xaml and App.xaml.cs to lowercase, so it doesn’t seem like there should be any issues.I also think consistency is very important.Thank you!
